# Bash piping in OSX prompts command not found, sometimes

Tags: bash, osx-lion, pipe, piping

In the OSX terminal :

```
du -h | sort -nr
-bash:  sort: command not found

which sort
/usr/bin/sort
```

The weird thing is: I tried reproducing the error and it seems to be totally random. My PATH echoed:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin:/Users/sytycs/.rvm/bin
```

This only occurs when piping and happens with `grep`, `more`, `less` etc.
Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: take a look at this other post in superuser https://superuser.com/questions/78245/how-to-disable-the-option-space-key-combination-for-non-breaking-spaces

Answer (score 37, accepted):

That space is not a space. Erase and replace it.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. I was not sure what you meant with "erase and replace it", but I removed the space between the "|“ and “sort“ and it seems to be working. Could you explain why, though?

Comment: Because it's not a space, it only *looks* like one.

Comment: You may not be typing it consistently (e.g. Option-Space looks like a space, but isn't), or cutting/pasting or using history from an earlier mistyped version.

Comment: I do this all the time. Mac keyboards (at least in some parts of the world) create the pipe-symbol with Alt+7 and immediately afterwards it's common to accidentally press Alt+Space, which causes the wrong character to be typed (not a space, but a hard-space or whatever they are called).

Comment: If you add `"\xC2\xA0": " "` to your `~/.inputrc` bash treats non-breaking spaces as normal ones. I [blogged about this](http://www.relativkreativ.at/articles/why-chaining-commands-with-pipes-in-mac-os-x-does-not-always-work) in more detail.

Answer (score 45):

This likely happens because you use a keyboard layout with a non-US layout (happened to me too). On German layouts, the pipe is typed with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>, so chances are high that you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> afterwards, which will produce a [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

A quick solution: Add the line

```
"\xC2\xA0": " "
```

to your `~/.inputrc` (if you are using bash). This will map non-breaking spaces to normal ones which should solve the problem.

If you want more detail (or if you are interested in how you can track down these kinds of issues), I wrote [a blog post](http://www.relativkreativ.at/articles/why-chaining-commands-with-pipes-in-mac-os-x-does-not-always-work) about it some time ago.

Comment: Thanks @Michael I still run into this every so often.

Comment: Awesome answer +1

Answer (score 0):

The trick with ~/.inputrc doesn't work for zsh. But here you can configure iTerm to send a space when you type alt+space, for instance

Answer (score 0):

Bash is so sensitive to **space** when you are piping. **Remove** them all.
I was facing the same problem by running this command:

```
|awk '{$1=$1};1' |  tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' |  sort | uniq 
| awk '{ print length, $0 }' | sort -n -s | cut -d" " -f2- > dest_file
```

the errors were as here:

```
zsh: command not found:   tr
zsh: command not found:   sort
```

then I removed all the spaced and it got resolved:

```
|awk '{$1=$1};1'|tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'|sort|uniq|awk '{ print length, $0 
}'|sort -n -s|cut -d" " -f2- >
```