# Command not found after pipe

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, grep

I'm using OS X Mavericks with zsh (technically the package oh-my-zsh).

I've been facing this bug for some time now and haven't found a way to fix it. Sometimes when I pipe a command it just says command not found.

For example, when I do a nmap network list scan like so `nmap -sL 192.168.2.0/24 | grep ')'` I sometimes get the error `zsh: command not found:  grep`. Even when I use arrow up button it won't work, so I have to rewrite the command, exactly the same, and it will work.

It is really annoying and it has happened occasionally with other commands and mostly after a pipe.

Any idea why this is occurring?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash piping in OSX prompts command not found, sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694442/bash-piping-in-osx-prompts-command-not-found-sometimes)

Answer (score 179, accepted):

The fact that it's happening only sometimes indicates that your input actually varies (subtly) from time to time.

It depends on what kind of keyboard you have, but I think it's likely that you're accidentally holding down the `Alt` key while you type the space after the pipe. `Alt+Space` is a non-breaking space, which zsh won't recognise.

Comment: holy *hit, you are right. Thank you so much. To easy to be sawn >.<

Comment: Elementary, Watson.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for this. My terminal does not show the "ugly space" that brakes it.

Comment: Came here in 2021 to be baffled about this. Thanks.

Comment: For what is worth, it also happens on debian bash with a PC (french) keyboard with [Alt gr] + space... Since [Alt gr] is necessary to produce the pipe on this keyboard, that happens quite often to me.

Comment: I was today years old when I found out.

Answer (score 24):

This is common error which happened in mac OS X when you copy ans paste command line.
what you can do is to delete the space before and after the |

for example  `kubectl get pods | grep bla-bla-bla` is now `kubectl get pods|grep bla-bla-bla`

hope that's help

Comment: very weird behaviour